# How can I always include "Applications" in the filter results of Unity Dash?

Tags: unity-dash

**Background:**

I mostly use Unity Dash to search for applications as well as files and folders. However, as shown in the below screenshot, `Applications` is not always included as a category in the `Filter results`.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Unity Dash]

**Question:**

How can I always include the `Applications` category in the `Filter results` of Unity Dash?

Comment: If you enable this manually, it should remember that option for next time. Doesn't that happen?

Comment: Clicking on the Applications filter (as well as the other filters) is a toggle.  When it click it, you either turn it on or turn it off.  If you turn it on it will **`always be included`** until you specifically click it again to turn it off.  You can tell the state by the white border around it when it's toggled on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on the `Filter Results` tab of the Unity Dash allows you to see your filter options or to modify your filter options.

The filter options you see are a toggle.  You can tell which ones are toggled on by the white border around the selection.  If there isn't a white border, then it's toggled off.  If it's off clicking the selection will toggle it on.

If you have a white border around your `Applications` it will be toggled on.  **It will always include "Applications" in the filter results** until you click the applications button again and turn it off (by removing the white border).

If you type something in the search area that that has a match for one of your filters (in this case you applications) you will see it in the search results under that category.  If the match comes up empty, the category will not show.  It will only show if a match is found.

You have the letters `voko` in your for your search.  You are not seeing the `Applications` category because it's not finding a match for `voko` in the application search.  Because you have the `Files & Folder` filter turn on, a match for your `voko` search has been found.  So the category for that match is displayed.  If you keep narrowing your search (for instance placing a bunch of `x`'s) until there isn't a match, your dash results will be blank.  You will neither see your `Applications` nor the `Files & Folder` category displayed.

The `Applications filter` is showing you applications that were installed with a `*.desktop` extension that has an entry in default locations like `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: Hi James, for me it does not remember the filter settings, sadly. On a random basis, `Applications` is being ticked off again.

Comment: @RobertOrzanna Does any of the other filters loose their settings?  Will you try turning on 5 or 6 or them and telling me which stays set and which looses their settings.  I'll check the bug reports.  The description in the answer is how it works.  If your case is different, it's a bug and needs to be analysed.  Also does this change happen on reboots or during an active session between boots.

Comment: I ticked all boxes. After a while—and during the same session—only `Applications` and `Files & Folders` remained active.